# Связать в одном поле 2 модели?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть 3 модели:

```
class category(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='название')

class page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='заголовок')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='текст')

class menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='заголовок')
    content = models.ForeignKey(Page or Category) # <- How to?
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Как сделать, что бы `menu.content` ссылалась либо на страницу, либо на категорию, и в зависимости от того, на что она ссылается в `menu.link` должно быть либо `category/<id>`, либо `page/<id>`?

Comment: В дальнейшем, типы контента могут добавляться...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно через [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), как-то так:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.IntegerField()
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Но, вроде бы, нет толкового метода ограничить на что может ссылаться GFK, разве что в БД пост-фактум (уже после заполнения таблицы content_types) засунуть констрейнты по ID, чтобы подстраховаться.

Другой вариант — через [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = ...
    link = ...

class Page(MenuItem):
    text = ...

...
```

Но, опять же, некрасиво — `MenuItem.objects` вернет объекты класса `MenuItem`, а не `Page`. Т.е. придется выбирать отдельно по каждой таблице и склеивать.

Третий вариант — если СУБД умеет наследование (как, скажем, [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-inherit.html)), то использовать его и raw SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE menu_items ( ... );
CREATE TABLE pages ( ...) INHERITS (menu_items);
```

Тогда `SELECT * FROM menu_items` может использовать все поля из таблиц-наследников. Но, опять же, это некрасиво — ломимся мимо Django'вского ORM'а. Хотя можно выкрутиться через unmanaged models и, возможно, представления для `SELECT ... FROM ONLY ...` (если они нужны; т.к. ORM никогда сам запрос не родит).

Четвертый вариант — завести два `ForeignKey`, `page` и `category`, и влепить констрейнт, что одно и только одно из них должно быть `NULL` (`None`). И сделать, для удобства, `@property` у модели, которое вернет то, что `is not None`. По мне так лучший из вариантов, но совершенно не подходит для ситуаций, когда типов объектов много.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что самый простой способ - это все-таки сделать 2 поля, `pagecontent` и `categorycontent`, и заполнять их по-разному в зависимости от содержания `link`.